# How to remove duplicates from a list of custom objects?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a custom class of objects with an assortment of various attributes of different types. I would like to remove duplicates from a list of these objects based on one of these attributes.

Something like this, but actually get a list of the objects rather than a list of the specified attribute.

```
filteredData = list(set([x.attribute[0] for x in objList]))
```

Comment: What exactly is the attribute? Do all the objects have this attribute? Are you looking for the objects that contain a certain value for this attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need realize methods **hash**  and **eq** on object

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.attr1 = a

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.attr1)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.attr1 == other.attr1

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.attr1)
```

Example:

```
l = [A(5), A(4), A(4)]
print list(set(l))
print list(set(l))[0].__class__  # ==> __main__.A. It's a object of class
```

Comment: In final list you receive your object not values of attribute